# New Clipboard API access to non `text/plain` content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard, clipboarddata

Using the new [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) I can easily read out the current content as text ([sample code](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/async-clipboard/)) and the API looks like it could support multiple 'types', but at least in Chrome and Edge it always only returns `text/plain`. Is this a bug/limitation in the new API, or should I do my call differently?

### Full example how to trigger this behavior

Note: make sure to copy rich text content beforehand. (This is not a snippet as the new clipboard API doesn't seem to work in iframes)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <div contenteditable>
      paste into this area for old api
    </div>
    <button id="async">async api</button>
    <script>
```

```js
      document.querySelector("#async").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        navigator.permissions
          .query({ name: "clipboard-read" })
          .then((result) => {
            // If permission to read the clipboard is granted or if the user will
            // be prompted to allow it, we proceed.

            if (result.state == "granted" || result.state == "prompt") {
              navigator.clipboard.read().then((data) => {
                console.log(data.map((d) => d.types)); // always returns only [['text/plain']]
              });
            }
          });
      });
      document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
        console.log(e.clipboardData.types); // returns for the same content ["text/plain", "text/html"]
      });
```

```html
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Chrome is still working on it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=897289

For the time being, only `text/plain` and `image/png` can be retrieved and written through this API.

Unfortunately, they also blocked the access of this feature to cross-origin frames, meaning almost all online js fiddlers, Stack-Snippets included.

So [here is a link to a code-sandbox external window](https://grduc.csb.app/), not sure how long these things last, and below is the main code of that sandbox:

```
  button.onclick = async (evt) => {
    const clipboard = navigator.clipboard;
    const item = (await clipboard.read())[0];
    const image =
      item.types.includes("image/png") && (await item.getType("image/png"));
    const text =
      item.types.includes("text/plain") && item.getType("text/plain");

    if (image) {
      document.body.appendChild(new Image()).src = URL.createObjectURL(
        image
      );
    }
    console.log(text);
  };
```

Note that the synchronous API accessible through the *ClipboardEvent*'s `clipboardData`, can access these types.

Comment: Current Chromium ticket state: "Given the security implications with this proposal, we're abandoning it."

Answer (score 0):

Since readText() (and read(), for that matter) returns an empty string if the clipboard isn't text, this code is safe.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API